# How to combine two pd dataframe, re-rank the ranking based on the score and return the entire row for the highest ranking?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine 2 pandas dataframe and rank the combined dataframe again, after that, extract the row with highest score/ with the 1st ranking as the return. I tried something shown below in my code but it return me the 1st index instead of 1st rank.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['Peter', 'James', 'John', 'Marry'], 'Score' : [6.1, 5.6, 6.8, 7.99], 
                   'ranking' :[ 3, 4, 2, 1]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['Albert', 'Kelsey', 'Janice'], 'Score' : [1.1, 8.2, 7], 
                   'ranking' :[ 3, 1, 2]})
pd_combine = pd.concat([df,df1], sort=False)
pd_combine.iloc[pd_combine['Score'].idxmax()]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the third line with this:

```
pd_combine = pd.concat([df,df1], sort=False).reset_index()
```

Problem was that you had duplicated indices. This change ensures that every row has its own unique id in this new combined data frame.

If you want to rank again entries in new, combined data frame use:

```
res = pd_combine.sort_values('Score',ascending=False)
res.ranking = range(1,len(res)+1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is exactly what I want! :)

Comment: Sorry for one add on question, is it possible to rank the ranking again in the combined dataframe? Because the ranking is still based on the separate dataframe instead of new combined dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sort=False`, specify `ignore_index=True`

```
pd_combine = pd.concat([df,df1], ignore_index=True)
```